# NotImplementedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline. Use of unknown opcode MAP_ADD at line 116 of <ipython-input-287-147d4798a88b>

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, numba

I try to launch a code with Numba and I get errors.

What I want to do is to compute the cosine similarity with a cosinus_sparse function. This class method I use in the search class method, then I call search in the results method. Although I added the @jit decorator before each method I have this implementation error that appears.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import math


class Search:

    def __init__(self, corpus, method='XTERM', stop_words='english', max_df=1.0, min_df=1, max_features=None):
        self.corpus = corpus
        self.method = method
        self.stop_words = stop_words
        self.max_df = max_df
        self.min_df = min_df
        self.max_features = max_features
        self.vectorization()
        self.get_shape()
        self.features_names = self.bag_of_word.get_feature_names()
        
    def vectorization(self):
        if self.method == 'XTERM':
            self.bag_of_word = CountVectorizer(stop_words=self.stop_words,
                                               max_df=self.max_df, min_df=self.min_df,
                                               max_features=self.max_features)
            self.corpus_vectorized = self.bag_of_word.fit_transform(self.corpus)
        elif self.method == 'TFxIDF':
            self.bag_of_word = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=self.stop_words,
                                               max_df=self.max_df, min_df=self.min_df,
                                               max_features=self.max_features)
            self.corpus_vectorized = self.bag_of_word.fit_transform(self.corpus)
        else:
            raise MethodError('Method provided is not valid')

    def get_shape(self):
        self.n_docs, self.n_terms = self.corpus_vectorized.shape


    def get_query(self, query):
        self.indexes = [self.features_names.index(q) for q in query if q in self.features_names]
        self.query_vec = np.zeros(self.n_terms)
        self.query_vec[self.indexes] = 1

    
    @staticmethod
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def cosinus_sparse(i, j):
        num = i.dot(j)
        spars = i * i.transpose()
        den = math.sqrt(spars[0, 0]) * math.sqrt(sum(j * j))
        if (den > 0):
            return int(num) / den
        else:
            return 0
        
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def search(self, q) -> dict:
        cc = {i: self.cosinus_sparse(self.corpus_vectorized[i, :], q) for i in range(self.n_docs)}
        cc = sorted(cc.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        return cc
    
    @jit
    def get_result(self) -> list:
        self.result = self.search(self.query_vec)

    def result_announcer(self):
        self.search_lenght = len([i for i in self.result if i[1] > 0])
        print('{} documents linked to your query where found'.format(search_lenght))
    

    def verif_query_vec(self, query):
        if int(sum(self.query_vec)) != len(query):
            raise QueryError('Error in query or query_vec')

    
    def processing(self, query):
        try:
            self.get_query(query)
            self.verif_query_vec(query)
            self.get_result()
            
        except NameError:
            self.vectorisation()
            self.get_shape()
            self.get_feature_names()
            self.get_query(query)
            self.verif_query_vec(query)
            self.get_result()
```

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

text = widgets.Text(
    value='',
    placeholder='Type words',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)
method_radio = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['XTERM', 'TFxIDF'],
#     value='TF',
    description='Method:',
    disabled=False
)
submit = widgets.Button(description = 'Search')

display(widgets.VBox([text, radio, submit]))
  
def handle_submit(sender):
    global query
    query = text.value.lower().split(' ')
    method = method_radio.value
    # instentiation de l'objet de recherche
    global search_obj
    search_obj = Search(corpus=corpus, method=method, )
    search_obj.processing(query)
    
submit.on_click(handle_submit)
```

Here is the error

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-288-025a488daa60> in handle_submit(sender)
     27     global search_obj
     28     search_obj = Search(corpus=corpus, method=method, )
---> 29     search_obj.processing(query)
     30 
     31 submit.on_click(handle_submit)

<ipython-input-287-147d4798a88b> in processing(self, query)
    167             self.get_query(query)
    168             self.verif_query_vec(query)
--> 169             self.get_result()
    170 
    171         except NameError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    365                     e.patch_message(''.join(e.args) + help_msg)
    366             # ignore the FULL_TRACEBACKS config, this needs reporting!
--> 367             raise e
    368 
    369     def inspect_llvm(self, signature=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    322                 argtypes.append(self.typeof_pyval(a))
    323         try:
--> 324             return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
    325         except errors.TypingError as e:
    326             # Intercept typing error that may be due to an argument

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py in _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     30         def _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs):
     31             with self:
---> 32                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     33         return _acquire_compile_lock
     34 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in compile(self, sig)
    653 
    654             self._cache_misses[sig] += 1
--> 655             cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
    656             self.add_overload(cres)
    657             self._cache.save_overload(sig, cres)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in compile(self, args, return_type)
     80                                       args=args, return_type=return_type,
     81                                       flags=flags, locals=self.locals,
---> 82                                       pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)
     83         # Check typing error if object mode is used
     84         if cres.typing_error is not None and not flags.enable_pyobject:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in compile_extra(typingctx, targetctx, func, args, return_type, flags, locals, library, pipeline_class)
    924     pipeline = pipeline_class(typingctx, targetctx, library,
    925                               args, return_type, flags, locals)
--> 926     return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
    927 
    928 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in compile_extra(self, func)
    372         self.lifted = ()
    373         self.lifted_from = None
--> 374         return self._compile_bytecode()
    375 
    376     def compile_ir(self, func_ir, lifted=(), lifted_from=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in _compile_bytecode(self)
    855         """
    856         assert self.func_ir is None
--> 857         return self._compile_core()
    858 
    859     def _compile_ir(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in _compile_core(self)
    842         self.define_pipelines(pm)
    843         pm.finalize()
--> 844         res = pm.run(self.status)
    845         if res is not None:
    846             # Early pipeline completion

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py in _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     30         def _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs):
     31             with self:
---> 32                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     33         return _acquire_compile_lock
     34 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in run(self, status)
    253                     # No more fallback pipelines?
    254                     if is_final_pipeline:
--> 255                         raise patched_exception
    256                     # Go to next fallback pipeline
    257                     else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in run(self, status)
    244                 try:
    245                     event(stage_name)
--> 246                     stage()
    247                 except _EarlyPipelineCompletion as e:
    248                     return e.result

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in stage_inline_pass(self)
    582                                             self.flags.auto_parallel,
    583                                             self.parfor_diagnostics.replaced_fns)
--> 584         inline_pass.run()
    585         # Remove all Dels, and re-run postproc
    586         post_proc = postproc.PostProcessor(self.func_ir)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\inline_closurecall.py in run(self)
     75 
     76                         if guard(self._inline_closure,
---> 77                                 work_list, block, i, func_def):
     78                             modified = True
     79                             break # because block structure changed

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\ir_utils.py in guard(func, *args, **kwargs)
   1358     """
   1359     try:
-> 1360         return func(*args, **kwargs)
   1361     except GuardException:
   1362         return None

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\inline_closurecall.py in _inline_closure(self, work_list, block, i, func_def)
    212         inline_closure_call(self.func_ir,
    213                             self.func_ir.func_id.func.__globals__,
--> 214                             block, i, func_def, work_list=work_list)
    215         return True
    216 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\inline_closurecall.py in inline_closure_call(func_ir, glbls, block, i, callee, typingctx, arg_typs, typemap, calltypes, work_list)
    253     callee_closure = callee.closure if hasattr(callee, 'closure') else callee.__closure__
    254     # first, get the IR of the callee
--> 255     callee_ir = get_ir_of_code(glbls, callee_code)
    256     callee_blocks = callee_ir.blocks
    257 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\ir_utils.py in get_ir_of_code(glbls, fcode)
   1572     f.__name__ = fcode.co_name
   1573     from numba import compiler
-> 1574     ir = compiler.run_frontend(f)
   1575     # we need to run the before inference rewrite pass to normalize the IR
   1576     # XXX: check rewrite pass flag?

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in run_frontend(func)
    168     interp = interpreter.Interpreter(func_id)
    169     bc = bytecode.ByteCode(func_id=func_id)
--> 170     func_ir = interp.interpret(bc)
    171     post_proc = postproc.PostProcessor(func_ir)
    172     post_proc.run()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\interpreter.py in interpret(self, bytecode)
    101         # Data flow analysis
    102         self.dfa = dataflow.DataFlowAnalysis(self.cfa)
--> 103         self.dfa.run()
    104 
    105         # Temp states during interpretation

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dataflow.py in run(self)
     26     def run(self):
     27         for blk in self.cfa.iterliveblocks():
---> 28             self.infos[blk.offset] = self.run_on_block(blk)
     29 
     30     def run_on_block(self, blk):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dataflow.py in run_on_block(self, blk)
     76         for offset in blk:
     77             inst = self.bytecode[offset]
---> 78             self.dispatch(info, inst)
     79         return info
     80 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dataflow.py in dispatch(self, info, inst)
     86         fname = "op_%s" % inst.opname.replace('+', '_')
     87         fn = getattr(self, fname, self.handle_unknown_opcode)
---> 88         fn(info, inst)
     89 
     90     def handle_unknown_opcode(self, info, inst):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dataflow.py in handle_unknown_opcode(self, info, inst)
     91         msg = "Use of unknown opcode {} at line {} of {}"
     92         raise NotImplementedError(msg.format(inst.opname, inst.lineno,
---> 93                                              self.bytecode.func_id.filename))
     94 
     95     def dup_topx(self, info, inst, count):

NotImplementedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: inline calls to locally defined closures)
Use of unknown opcode MAP_ADD at line 116 of <ipython-input-287-147d4798a88b>
```

How do I fix this error?
Thanks a lot for your help.